# Unit testing socket.io with karma and jasmine

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, jasmine, karma-runner

The project I am working on makes use of socket.io for some of the components of the UI.
I am trying to write unit tests for this particular section of the application. I am using: [angular-socket-io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io) and [angular-socket.io-mock](https://github.com/nullivex/angular-socket.io-mock) to mock the server side component.

I am using everything at the simplest level, so I have my factory:

```
  myapp
    .factory('notify', function (socketFactory) {
      return socketFactory();
    });
```

This is the controller

```
    myapp
      .controller('NotificationsCtrl', function ($scope, notify) {
        $scope.items = []
        notify.emit("loadItems",{},function(res){
          $scope.items = res.res
        });
      });
```

and finally the unit test:

```
  describe('Controller: NotificationsCtrl', function () {

    // load the controller's module
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var NotificationsCtrl,
      scope;

    // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      NotificationsCtrl = $controller('NotificationsCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
      });
    }));

    it('The scope.items should change somehow', function() {
      expect(scope.items.length).toEqual(3);
    });

  });
```

I cannot realize what is missing to make this working.
How should I change my code to make it happen?

Thanks